# What is the difference between Prism's IContainer and IUnityContainer?

Tags: wpf, unity-container, prism

I've got a **Prism** project with code that I've gotten from **various sources**, everything is working quite nicely, but I noticed that in some modules I inject

```
IContainer container
```

and in other modules I inject

```
IUnityContainer container
```

IContainer only seems to have **Components, Add, and Remove** while IUnityContainer has dozens of methods.

I'm changing IContainer to IUnityContainer often so that I can use the latter's resolve methods. **What is the difference between these two and why would I want to use IContainer?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are really two different things with different purposes.

The IUnityContainer is a dependency injection container that supports all of the things you'd need to do in a dependency injection / service location scenario, like BuildUp, Resolve, Register, etc.  You can read more about Unity (which is actually part of Enterprise Library and *used* by the CAG) by going here: [Unity on Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/unity)

IContainer is used to create a generic container for objects that are IComponents.  It's used by a number of components and is in the .NET Framework in System.ComponentModel.  It is not related to Unity or the CAG in any direct way.  I would consider this to be something that was more Windows Forms specific and less WPF, although you can use IComponents in WPF indirectly. [IContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icontainer.aspx)

When doing any kind of dependency injection, you should be using IUnityContainer, not IContainer.